# Convert a number to $1$ or $-1$

Tags: functions

Is there a way to convert any number to either $1$ or $-1$ depending on its sign?
For example:

```
 13    =  1
-13    = -1
-670.2 = -1
 8.22  =  1
```

Lets say X is the number, i could do X / X and i would always get $1$ but the minus would get lost.

Comment: Perhaps the signum function is what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function.

Comment: thank you, both answers are correct.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [convergence] ?

Comment: sry i dont know what the correct tag is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the usual way would be to use the absolute value:

$$\frac{x}{|x|}.$$

It won't work for $x=0,$ though.

If you don't like absolute value, then you can replace it by $\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for i will mark it as correct answer